# Is it safe to eat more Vitamin B than you need?

Tags: micronutrients, medical-myths, safety, absorption-absorb, vitamin-b

My uncle who worked in pharmaceutical factory, says it is safe to eat more Vitamin B than you need, because people have limited absorption of Vitamin. Is this ture ?

Comment: Perhaps theoretically but note there are several forms of B vitamins. Studies have been performed in some animals which showed that  vitamin B6 is neurotoxic, causing peripheral
neuropathy, with ataxia, muscle weakness, and loss of balance in dogs given
200 mg of pyridoxine per kg of body weight for 40 to 75 days.Similarly other B vitamins pose toxicity if taken in very large amounts over considerable amount of time. Actually this question somewhat broad and needs considerable research and enough time to post an answer which I would have done if I had time.